# Clear the current path in CGContextRef?

Tags: macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics

I am looking for way to clear the current path in the `CGContextRef`? I want to replace with current path in `CGContextRef` with new `CGPathRef`.

I thought I could you `CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath`? But for that too, I have to clear the current path stored in `CGContextRef`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CGContextBeginPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextBeginPath) clears the current path:

> A graphics context can have only a single path in use at any time. If
>   the specified context already contains a current path when you call
>   this function, Quartz discards the old path and any data associated
>   with it.

Comment: Thanks. Spot on. Damm it! I want to kill myself. Thats why we read documentation. Thanks again.

Comment: @MacGeek The function really has a misleading name.